# Missing url rewrites in Magento after product change or addition

Tags: php, magento

I have the community-feedback mod installed in Magento and I've had lots of issues with it. I am now fixing the bugs in it myself as the developer been of no help. One of the issues I am having is that when I add or change any product, the url rewrites for posts/tags from the extension are erased. I end up having to clear the table and then manually reindexing the cart.

I would like to know which function is responsible during product additions/changes for clearing/deleting url rewrites.

Comment: "as the developer been of no help" how much did you pay him for his work ?

Comment: It was a module that I purchased and they want access to our cart which I cannot provide as there is a lot of custom development and their are many mods.